# Any way to fill an image surface with a color? (Canvas)

Tags: html, canvas

I've searching a way to fill an image surface with a color with canvas but didn't find what i'm looking for.

Is there actually any way to do it?

There is an example of what i'm talking about:

If the image is like this:

[image]

I would need to paint this with canvas:

[image]

Just fill the actual image surface with a color (black in this case).

I think this Android method does the same, so I hope there is something similar on canvas.

```
imageView.setColorFilter(Color.RED);
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use composition mode to do this, more specifically the source-in:

```
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-in";
ctx.fillRect(x, y, w, h); // fill the image area using current color
```

```js
// Using the original colored logo in OPs post:
var img = new Image; img.onload = go; img.src = "//i.stack.imgur.com/kv435.png";
function go() {
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  c.width = this.width; c.height = this.height;
  ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
  
  // change color
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-in";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);      // def. color is black
}
```

```html
<canvas id=c></canvas>
```

What's important to be aware of though is that composite operations works with the alpha channel. If the image doesn't have an alpha channel but just a white background, this approach won't work. In that case you would need to iterate over each pixel and replace all non-white pixels to the target color pixel.

For this approach you can use `getImageData()`. But my recommendation is to prepare the image so it has an alpha channel embedded before processing.